# Comparing one date with starting date and ending date with duplicates

Tags: pandas, dataframe, date, duplicates, compare

i have the below sample of data, and i need to create a function that will take a sales date and compare it with the below dates and returns the discount name & percentage, but as below the discount dates are not unique and some times overlaps, so in case the date falls in two different discounts names it has to return the highest duplicate discount name based on the percentage in case the sale date falls in more than one.

```
Discount Name   Start Date  End Date    Percentage
0   First   2020-07-24  2020-11-25  0.10
1   First   2020-09-13  2020-10-29  0.10
2   First   2020-12-07  2020-12-10  0.10
3   First   2020-12-28  2021-01-19  0.10
4   First   2020-06-14  2020-06-14  0.10
5   Second  2020-06-16  2020-06-18  0.15
6   Second  2020-06-21  2020-06-22  0.15
7   Second  2020-06-22  2020-06-23  0.15
8   Second  2020-07-07  2020-07-08  0.15
9   Third   2020-06-02  2020-06-12  0.20
10  Third   2020-05-19  2020-06-01  0.20
11  Third   2020-05-06  2020-05-17  0.20
12  Third   2020-04-30  2020-05-03  0.20
```

[Screen Shot of Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNTwP.png)

i truly hope that someone can help me on this. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This function should do the trick

```py
def discout_rate(df, sales_date):
    return df[(df['Start Date'] <= sales_date) & (df['End Date'] >= sales_date)]['Percentage'].max()
```

The `sales_date` should be of type `datetime.datetime` and the columns `Start Date` and `End Date` too.